# Login into Facebook in Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I'm trying to login into Facebook from an Android application so I generate my key hashes with this command : 
`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

When I click on my Facebook Login button, I got this error :

```
Invalid key hash. the key hash XXXXX/XXXXX does not match any stored key hashes. Configure you app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/app_id
```

Do you have any idea?
Thanks !